# How to set check of PDRadioButton

Tags: java, pdfbox

How can I set the value of PDradioButton to checked in java pdfbox 2.0.4. I found some answers here where the PDradioCollection was used but in my version of pdfbox it is not avalaible and it seems like the PDradioButton itself does not have any method to do that. So I am really stucked here right now. Do you know any way how to do this ? I would be very thankfull for every help.

Comment: what do you get when calling `getOnValues()` on the field? The best would be 1) update to 2.0.5, 2) share the PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your answer I already solved it. `getOnValues()` wokrs with `setValue()`

Comment: Please press the green checkmark, so that others know this is the best answer.